# Bootstrap Hamburger menu not working on Electron (working on Node)

Tags: jquery, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, electron

Small Node app working fine on C9, Heroku and locally.

The local version on Node works fine but the Electron version works Bootstrap (the theme, color, etc...) but the hamburger menu is not working, as if jQuery was not installed.

I don't use jQuery on the package.json, I call jQuery with...

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

...on the footer of views/partials.

With this configuration works fine on Node but not on Electron.  **Do I need to do something more for Electron?**